# Using \item in the first column of a table

Tags: tables, enumerate

I have a list and a sublist both created with `\enumerate`, and each item in the sublist consists of two halves (both math). How could I separate the halves so that the first half of each row is left-aligned with all the other first-halves and the second half of each row is left-aligned with the second-halves?

My first thought was using `\item` within `\tabular`, but I couldn't quite get it to work. The simplest example to offer comes from page 6 of Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{tabular}{ll}$\{\emptyset\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$\end{tabular}

    \item \begin{tabular}{ll}$\{\emptyset\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$\end{tabular}

    \item \begin{tabular}{ll}$\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$\end{tabular}

    \item \begin{tabular}{ll}$\{\{\emptyset\}\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$\end{tabular}

    \item \begin{tabular}{ll}$\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$\end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The result is below. As you can see, the second halves of each subitem are not aligned.

[image]

I did find other questions related to enumerated lists within tables, but I'm relatively new to LaTeX (and StackExchange) so I wasn't sure which solution was right for me. I'm looking for the simplest solution, but if it has already been supplied in another question, please point me there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Wouldn't it be better to use an `align` environment in which you can use labels and refer to a specific 'equation'?

Comment: I would also suggest a user - defined macro for the `{...}` set descriptions. Perhaps `\set` from `brakets` package is useful here

Comment: is this  code correct ( i mean in set theory)

Comment: @touhami: As long as empty sets are involved I would say yes....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well this is not math.sx but c) and d) are wrong

Comment: @touhami: I am only a Physicist and have no idea of `set` theory in its full range, so I have to believe you ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two possible ways, without `align` etc. if it must be an `enumerate` version.

The reason, why the columns are not aligned from one item to the next is, that each `\begin{tabular}{ll}...\end{tabular}` has different column widths. If all would columns would have the same width, then the columns would be aligned. I've done this in the second version below, the `*{2}{p{\mycolumnwidth}}` sets two (2) left aligned `parbox` columns of width `\mycolumnwidth`, set here to 3.5cm. Change to appropiate values...

The first version fakes the inner `enumerate` by usage of an automatic row counting, using one common `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{rowcounter}
\renewcommand{\therowcounter}{(\alph{rowcounter})}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\stepcounter{rowcounter}\therowcounter\arraybackslash}r}

\newlength{\mycolumnwidth}

\setlength{\mycolumnwidth}{3.5cm}
\begin{document}


%%%%

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{Rll}
   & $\{\emptyset\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ \tabularnewline
   & $\{\emptyset\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ \tabularnewline
   & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ \tabularnewline
   & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ \tabularnewline
   & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$
\end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{\mycolumnwidth}}}$\{\emptyset\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$\end{tabular}
    \item \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{\mycolumnwidth}}}$\{\emptyset\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$\end{tabular}
    \item \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{\mycolumnwidth}}}$\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$\end{tabular}
    \item \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{\mycolumnwidth}}}$\{\{\emptyset\}\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$\end{tabular}
    \item \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{\mycolumnwidth}}}$\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$\end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personally, I recommend neither of them ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, I define a `tabenumerate` environment and a `\tabitem` command, which mimick a 2nd level enumerate environment within a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcounter{tabenum}
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}{%
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}\setlength\extrarowheight{\itemsep}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\eqmakebox[A][r]{(\alph{tabenum})}\hskip\labelsep}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\qquad}l}
}
{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
        \begin{tabenumerate}
          \tabitem $\{\emptyset\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$\\
          \tabitem $\{\emptyset\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$\\
          \tabitem $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$\\
          \tabitem $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$\\
          \tabitem $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$
        \end{tabenumerate}
        %
  \item
        \begin{tabenumerate}
          \tabitem $\{\emptyset\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$\\
          \tabitem $\{\emptyset\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$\\
          \tabitem $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$\\
          \tabitem $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$\\
          \tabitem $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$ & $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not \subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$
        \end{tabenumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]